# debugging connection with urllib2+httplib.debuglevel sometimes not showing debug info

Tags: python, urllib2, httplib

Trying to get a login script working, I kept getting the same login page returned, so I turned on debugging of the http stream (can't use wireshark or the like because of https).

I got nothing, so I copied the example, it works.  Any query to google.com works, but to my target page does not show debugging, what is the difference?  If it was a redirect I would expect to see the first get/redirect header, and http://google redirects as well.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import pdb

h=urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(h)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
print '================================'
data = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com').read()
print '================================'
data = urllib2.urlopen('https://google.com').read()
print '================================'
data = urllib2.urlopen('https://members.poolplayers.com/default.aspx').read()
print '================================'
data = urllib2.urlopen('https://google.com').read()
```

When I run I get this.

```
$ python ex.py 
================================
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n'
header: Location: http://www.google.com/
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
header: Date: Sat, 02 Jul 2011 16:20:11 GMT
header: Expires: Mon, 01 Aug 2011 16:20:11 GMT
header: Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
header: Server: gws
header: Content-Length: 219
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Connection: close
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Sat, 02 Jul 2011 16:20:12 GMT
header: Expires: -1
header: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
header: Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=4ca9123c4f8b617f:FF=0:TM=1309623612:LM=1309623612:S=o3GqHRj5_3BkKFuJ; expires=Mon, 01-Jul-2013 16:20:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
header: Set-Cookie: NID=48=eZdXW-qQQC2fRrXps3HpzkGgeWbMCnyT_taxzdvW1icXS1KSM0SSYOL7B8-OPsw0eLLAbvCW863Viv9ICDj4VAL7dmHtF-gsPfro67IFN5SP6WyHHpLL7JsS_-MOvwSD; expires=Sun, 01-Jan-2012 16:20:12 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
header: Server: gws
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Connection: close
================================
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Sat, 02 Jul 2011 16:20:14 GMT
header: Expires: -1
header: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
header: Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=d613768b3704482b:FF=0:TM=1309623614:LM=1309623614:S=xLxMwBVKEG_bb1bo; expires=Mon, 01-Jul-2013 16:20:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
header: Set-Cookie: NID=48=im_KcHyhG2LrrGgLsQjYlwI93lFZa2jZjEYBzdn-xXEyQnoGo8xkP0234fROYV5DScfY_6UbbCJFtyP_V00Ji11kjZwJzR63LfkLoTlEqiaY7FQCIky_8hA2NEqcXwJe; expires=Sun, 01-Jan-2012 16:20:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
header: Server: gws
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Connection: close
================================
================================
send: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Sat, 02 Jul 2011 16:20:16 GMT
header: Expires: -1
header: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
header: Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=dc2cb55e6476c555:FF=0:TM=1309623616:LM=1309623616:S=o__g-Zcpts392D9_; expires=Mon, 01-Jul-2013 16:20:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
header: Set-Cookie: NID=48=R5gy1aTMjL8pghxQmfUkJaMLc3SxmpFxu5XpoZELAsZrdf8ogQLwyo9Vbk_pRkoETvKE-beWbHHBZu3xgJDt6IsjwmSHPaMGSzxXvsWERxsbKwQMy-wlLSfasvUq5x6q; expires=Sun, 01-Jan-2012 16:20:16 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
header: Server: gws
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Connection: close
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need an HTTP**S**Handler:

```
h = urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=1)
```